# Home Button 'pressed' detection when phone locked

Tags: java, android

This is a general question about android java programming.

Is there a way (when the phone is locked) to detect, if the home button is pressed for some seconds?

Answer (score 2):

The home is not available on all phones since a hardware button is not a requirement.

Comment: That's correct. But is it possible on all android phones which have an home button?